# Transcendental numbers (field extension/sum/product)

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, transcendental-numbers

Let $K \subset L$ be a field extension and $a,b \in L$ transcendental numbers over $K$.

How to show that $a+b$ and $ab$ are not both algebraic over $K$?

I used this:

My idea was to consider $K \subset K(a+b,ab) \subset K(a,b)$

Then $[K(a,b):K]=[K(a,b):K(a+b,ab)][K(a+b,ab):K]$

Since $[K(a,b):K]=\infty$ for $a,b$ transcendental, it follows that $a+b$ and $ab$ are not both algebraic.

I'm not sure if this argumentation is right.

Or how to conclude that $a+b$ and $ab$ are not both algebraic?

Comment: You used the tower law incorrectly, it should be $[K(a,b):K]=[K(a,b):K(a+b,ab)][K(a+b,ab):K]$.

Comment: $b = c/a,a+b=d$ then $a+c/a = d$ means $a$ is algebraic over $K(c,d)$.

Comment: Consider the equation $X^2-(a+b)X+ab=0$.

Comment: Since [maybe you didn't understand](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3478831/733812). Your argument was almost done, except for the equation of the degrees. You have that $[K(a,b):K]=[K(a,b):K(a+b,ab)]\cdot[K(a+b,ab):K]$. Since $a$ and $b$ are the roots of $X^2-(a+b)X+ab=0$, then $[K(a,b):K(a+b,ab)]\leq 2$. If $a+b$ and $ab$ are both transcendental over $K$, then $[K(a+b,ab):K]$ is finite. It follows that $[K(a,b):K]$ must be finite, contradicting that $a,b$ are transcendental over $K$.

Comment: How can the equation $X^2-(a+b)X+ab=0$ be found? And why does it follow that $[K(a,b):K(a+b,ab)] \leq 2$?

Answer (score 1):

If $a+b=\alpha$ with $\alpha$ algebraic over $K$, then $ab=a(\alpha-a)=\beta$ with $\beta$ algebraic over $K$. But then $K(a)$ is a finite extension of $K(\alpha,\beta)$ and hence $a$ is algebraic over $K$, contradiction.

Comment: Is there a way to show this with $K \subset K(a+b,ab) \subset K(a,b)$? I thought about using $[K(a,b):K(a+b,ab)]= [K(a,b):K(a)]\cdot [K(a):K(a)]$, but I'm not sure if this works or how to conclude.